# Calculating energy released in nuclear fission (inclusion of all fission products)

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

[image]

To answer this question, shouldn't we include the masses of the neutrons and the electrons in the given nuclear reaction? If I do that, I obviously get a slightly different answer from the one published. (Difference of about 4%). Why haven't they included masses of the neutrons and the electrons in their answer?

Also, I've never seen (free?) electrons as products of nuclear fission. Does that happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way would you include the masses in your calculation?  The *difference* in the masses is already included (since that accounts for the different binding energies).

Comment: I was thinking like this....... All masses in dalton......

(Mass of uranium + Mass of 1 neutron) - (Mass of molybdenum + mass of lanthanum + Mass of 2 neutrons + Mass of 7 electrons)

Would this be wrong?

If they hadn't given the table, we should still be able to find the energy released. And I thought that can be done by finding the difference in the masses of reactants and products.

Comment: The equation is just plain wrong in the details. If the 7 electrons are made, then they would be violating not just conservation of charge (since everything else is not written as charged), but also conservation of lepton numbers (neutrinos are not involved). The equation you wrote in the above comment is correct except you can omit the electrons. I just used the mass defect to get a simpler answer. The textbook is so sloppy, 4% difference is about tolerated.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks much!